# TSQL NVARCHAR Conversion Error inside CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-when

This select is driving me crazy.
The error is:

> Conversion error converting nvarchar value '17.30 h' to int data type.

Data is:

```
(DateTime)   (Nvarchar)  (DateTime)
DATAINICI    DATAMANUAL  DATAFI
null         17.30 h     10/01/2015
01/01/2015   20.30 h     null
```

And the statement is:

```
CASE WHEN  dbo.Activitat.DataInici is null 
THEN DATEPART(DAY,Activitat.Datafi) 
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), dbo.Activitat.DataManual)
END
```

Comment: Where is casting to int?

Comment: can you show the whole statement? Are you sure it is failing there? Try commenting out this section, will you still get the same error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting this error because of implicit conversion. One part of `CASE` returns `NVARCHAR(50)`  i.e. `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), dbo.Activitat.DataManual)` which cannot be converted into an `int` and the other returns an `int` i.e. `DATEPART(DAY,Activitat.Datafi)`.

Something like this will also return the same error.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 1 ELSE 'errorstring' END
```

You should `CONVERT` and return `NVARCHAR(50)` in both cases so there is no implicit conversion. Something like this.

```
CASE WHEN  dbo.Activitat.DataInici is null 
THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),DATEPART(DAY,Activitat.Datafi))
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), dbo.Activitat.DataManual)
END
```

Comment: Great catch. Didn't even think of it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay ughai (months, I'm aware).
But finally done!